# Need to do complex lookups and referencing of data across differently sized samples in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So, some background: I have a Google Sheets document with several sheets of information.

Two sheets hold data that needs to be checked against one another.

Sheet A is a list of contact data (and many other columns of classifying data that is irrelevant to this process, but makes it difficult to do all of this with a single sheet).

Sheet B is a shorter list of names (all of whom are on Sheet A), a date and a dollar amount for each.

When data is entered into B, we enter either the street address or email they provide us at the time as a way of ensuring that two people with the same name do not get mis-matched. If an email is provided, we try to use that.

I need to create a third sheet (C) for easily displaying the data from B with the contact information of the corresponding names stored in A.

While this may not seem complex, I have been running into a lot of issues making this work.

---

example:

Sheet A: Contact data

Name   |   Street Address   |   City   |   Prov   |   Postal   |  Email   |

John Smith  |  123 Smith Lane  |  Smithtown  |  ON  | x0x 0x0  |  [blank]  |

Jane Doe  | [blank]  |  [blank]  | [blank]  |  [blank] |  Doe@doecorp.co  |

Tim Philips  |  111 Philips Crt  |  Phillipston  |  ON  |  z2z 2z2  |  [blank]   |

Joe Test  | [blank]  |  [blank]  | [blank]  |  [blank] |  Joe@testorg.ca  |

---

Sheet B: Donations

Name   |   Street Address   |   Email   |   Date received   |   Amount (2018)

John Smith  |  [blank]  |  smith@smithorg.org  |  20/NOV/2018  |  $175  |

Joe Test  |  [blank]  |  joe@testorg.ca  |  15/OCT/2018  |  $200  |

---

Sheet C: output for mail merging (Filter-sorted by email addresses)

Name   |   Address   |   Email   |   Date received   |   Amount (2018)  |

Joe Test  |  [blank]  |  joe@testorg.ca  |  15/OCT/2018  |  $200  |

John Smith  |  23 Smith Lane  Smithtown, ON  x0x 0x0  |  [blank]  |  20/NOV/2018  |  $175  |

---

Ideally, the individual mailing address fields from A would be pulled and combined into a single cell in the end result. (we use the others to sort and filter our data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should put you on the right track, click [on the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sh8cnGx_tFY6PL9OJkGq2qG5hbG8e9DNGRaiius2g6g/edit?usp=sharing) for the whole spreadsheet.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. This is exactly what we are looking to do. (although it shows up with N/A on those fields it does not find a match for)

Comment: Update: If any donation is logged using a mailing address, it will only ever show the street address in Merge. If the street address is removed from the Donations sheet, the full address appears in Merge

Comment: The columns are different because of the difference in our test and actual sheets.  but this modification to the address column of Merge fixed the issue

`code` =if(Donations!B2<>"",
Donations!B2,
index(Database!$C$2:$C$50,MATCH(A2,Database!$B$2:$B$50,0))&" "&
index(Database!$D$2:$D$50,MATCH(A2,Database!$B$2:$B$50,0))&" "&
index(Database!$E$2:$E$50,MATCH(A2,Database!$B$2:$B$50,0))&" "&
index(Database!$F$2:$F$50,MATCH(A2,Database!$B$2:$B$50,0)))
`code`

EDIT: No it did not. But those without either street or email will use the name and get the corresponding address